# WiFi issues in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (still disconnect-reconnect, finally stops working)

Tags: wireless

My wireless adapter (AWUS1900 with this driver https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git) still disconnects and reconnects and after a bit, it disconnects and can't reconnect to the network; I have to reboot the system. It make me crazy !

Every time this happen, I see this message on `dmesg` command

```
[ 3827.872912] audit: type=1107 audit(1575393261.050:191): pid=1017 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.12" mask="receive" pid=2175 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1047 peer_label="unconfined"
            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

and it is full of this messages.

What is it mean ? Is it related to my problem ? How can I fix it ?

Another strange thing is that every command to modify the wireless behavior doesn't seem to work. 
For example if I type:

```
iw dev wlan0 get power_save
```

it return `on` so I set it to off

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

and it works for a while and then it back to the previous status (power_save on). I also set the usb suspensions to -1 on the kernel boot to not suspend the usb and make the wireless stop working.

But if I put my phone in hotspot mode (close to my wireless) my pc goes online instantly.

INFO about wireless card
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: **:**:**:**:**:**
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=88XXau ip=192.168.43.55 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

Comment: @K7AAY The question is not about Kali. The drivers is from Kali repo, that doesn't make the question off-topic. because the best realtek drivers are there at the moment.

Comment: @K7AAY I'm not asking about kali, I only notice I'm using this driver https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu. Kali Linux is off-topic on this site. You may have to resolve your problem using the Kali Linux forum

Comment: I've withdrawn my suggestion this is off topic and clarified the first graf to so state.

Comment: @Bob91 Remove that `Kali`, noone reads anything else.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes I did it, thanks. Hope someone reads the entire question